# email alert if program crashes

Tags: monitoring, notifications, alert

I have a program which needs to be constantly running on my Windows XP box. When I'm away from home (or even when I'm at home) I'd like to get an email notification if that program were to ever crash, which it does occasionally. If it is a scheduled task that monitors it a 5m interval between checks is OK.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Write a program to do that? And if you're not a coder, you should ask this question SU, because then it is clearly a software recommendation.

Comment: I'm fine with writing a program to do it, but I would prefer a simple batch file using win scheduled tasks if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write simple windows service to monitor your task. But what if your machine is down?

You can go a step further and integrate with [AlertGrid](http://alert-grid.com) service.
Each time your program executes some logic it should send signal to AlertGrid. Than you can set up rule like 'if my program hasn't responded for more than 5 minutes -> send Email/SMS'.

There are [some examples](http://alert-grid.com/documentation/integration-code-samples/) in various programming languages how to do this, so you don't need to be a seasoned coder.

This assumes that you have access to your source code, if not you can use [AlertGrid Basic monitor](http://alert-grid.com/tools/plugins/simple-monitor/)  which will send list of available processes to AlertGrid and if your program is not on a processes list then you might get email alert.

AlertGrid's Free account is enough for this case.

PS: I am a developer in AlertGrid team. We would be glad to help you in case of any questions.

Hope that helps!